# File input not terminating

Tags: python-2.7, user-input

I am trying to use the below code in my Spyder IDE.

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

When I try to run this is ipython console it's not even responding. While if I run the same in python console it's taking input but doing nothing and not taking EOL with `CTRL + D`

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users.....)
hello
how are you
```

Stackoverflow is not showing that funny character above on copy/paste. It's like a small L turned upside/down.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Ctrl+D isn't the end of input command on Windows, Ctrl+Z is...

Comment: Same case with `ctrl+Z` it's just doing nothing.